# Como fazer uma busca de perfis com características semelhantes aos interesses de outro perfil em um site de relacionamento?

Tags: algoritmo

Preciso selecionar vários clientes de um site de relacionamentos que eu estou desenvolvendo e ordenar por compatibilidade com o perfil da pessoa ou seja, quanto mais características semelhantes maior a compatibilidade e alem disso tenho que fazer uma espécie de "contador" para exibir a porcentagem de compatibilidade...

o meu principal problema está em sempre retornar resultados, mesmo que nenhuma característica  bata com o interesse da pessoa e desenvolver uma forma de exibir a "compatibilidade" entre as duas pessoas...

### O mais importante é a lógica de como chegar no resultado e não o código pronto

> Tabela Carateristica

```
id
nome
sobrenome
cidade
estadocivil
altura
peso
fisico
pele
olhos
filhos
querofilhos
bebo
fumo
denominacao
frequencia
importancia
igreja
sou
procuro
```

> Tabela Interesse

```
id
cidade
estadocivil
altura_min
altura_max
peso_min
peso_max
fisico
pele
olhos
filhos
quer_filhos
bebe
fuma
denominacao
frequencia
importancia
```

**Ainda não cheguei em uma lógica de como fazer isso por isso não tenho nenhum código para postar para poder orientar melhor vocês, mas assim que tiver eu acrescento aqui.**

Comment: Mesmo que você não tenha saído do 0, é melhor postar suas tentativas iniciais, as características do Banco de Dados, links da sua pesquisa inicial... Quanto mais informação à respeito do seu caso concreto, mais fácil é prover uma resposta adequada. Confira o guia [ask].

Comment: adicionei o que eu podia para ajudar @brasofilo

Comment: Creio que você vai depender mais da api do site de relacionamento disponibilizará para você. Até se consegue fazer o sistema se autenticar e começar a varrer o site ( um spider + webcrawler ) mas provavelmente o site de relacionamento te barrará.

Comment: @FlávioGranato na verdade eu desenvolvi o site, e essa é uma consulta interna no site... não vou fazer requisição por api mas sim criar uma pagina no site que vai exibir isso...

Comment: Achei a pergunta muito interessante, mas não acho que as tags estejam corretas. A pergunta me parece ser muito mais a respeito do método do que de uma ou outra tecnologia.

Comment: @LuizVieira qual tag você acha que se enquadraria melhor nessa duvida?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Verdade, eu nem sugeri uma. Foi mals. Bom, olhando as [tags que já existem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags), acho que `algoritmo` casa bem. Mas, de todas as formas, você pode criar também uma tag nova (ainda não vi perguntas assim por aqui). Talvez `compatibilidade` e/ou `métrica`?

Comment: @LuizVieira inseri a tag `algoritmo` mas ainda não posso criar tags novas para inserir métrica como uma possibilidade...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa definir é a forma como representará a compatibilidade entre dois indivíduos A e B. Você mesmo menciona o termo "porcentagem" na sua pergunta, então acho que o mais apropriado para você seja utilizar valores entre 0 e 1 de forma que 0 represente nenhuma compatibilidade e 1 represente compatibilidade total. Valores entre esses limites definiriam o grau de compatibilidade.

A forma mais simples de se obter essa compatibilidade é calcular uma "distância" (ou similaridade) entre os indivíduos por meio de suas características. Imaginando que dois indivíduos A e B completamente iguais em termos de suas características seriam totalmente compatíveis, o resultado esperado seria 1. Essa abstração pode ser feita para cada característica individualmente. Por exemplo, considere inicialmente a idade.

Ao assumir-se que dois indivíduos completamente compatíveis teriam a mesma idade (e esse é um ponto bastante discutível - mais detalhes posteriormente), uma medição possível seria a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável `DIF_MAX` contém a diferença máxima entre a maior e a menor idade disponível na sua base de dados (que pode ser um valor previamente calculado conforme a base de dados é atualizada) e serve para normalizar (isto é, manter o resultado entre 0 e 1) a diferença absoluta entre as idades dos indivíduos A e B (respectivamente as variáveis `idadeA` e `idadeB`). A similaridade resultante é igual a `1 - diferença absoluta`, e faz com que dessa forma indivíduos com *exatamente a mesma idade* tenham similaridade TOTAL, ou seja, igual a 1 (já que `1 - (0 / DIF_MAX) = 1 - 0 = 1`) e indivíduos com a máxima diferença entre idades tenham similaridade NULA, ou seja, igual a 0 (já que `1 - (DIF_MAX / DIF_MAX) = 1 - 1 = 0`).

No caso desse campo (idade), o fato de ser um valor numérico facilita porque se pode usar essa abordagem numérica. No caso de campos de valores enumeráveis (cor dos olhos, por exemplo), você pode representar cada valor como um número inteiro distinto e aplicar a mesma abordagem (sendo que `DIF_MAX` será igual ao número de possíveis valores para o campo), ou simplesmente aplicar uma abordagem lógica/booleana em que a similaridade é 1 se e somente se os indivíduos tiverem exatamente o mesmo valor e 0 caso contrário (isso também depende da interpretação de compatibilidade, que eu discuto a seguir).

Uma vez tendo-se as similaridades para cada campo, uma compatibilidade geral pode ser facilmente obtida com uma média simples ou ponderada (se determinados campos forem mais importantes do que outros) dos valores por campo (a variável `NUM_CARAC` representa o número de características, ou seja, o número de campos de cada indivíduo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa "compatibilidade" entre indivíduos muito provavelmente deve ser calculada previamente pelo sistema, e não no momento da consulta. Deve ser fácil manter uma tabela comparando cada par de indivíduos, e seus valores podem ser utilizados para ordenar a lista de potenciais relações no momento de uma consulta (dessa forma, mesmo que um indivíduo qualquer tenha baixa compatibilidade com os demais na sua base, sempre haverá listagens para serem exibidas).

---

Finalmente eu gostaria de discutir algumas questões importantes. Muito embora essa abordagem que eu acabo de sugerir possa funcionar, eu honestamente não sei se ela é a melhor forma de obter um bom resultado. A avaliação da compatibilidade entre pessoas apenas por meio das diferenças de idade é pouco útil sozinha, mas ela pode ajudar num contexto maior. Porém, qual deve ser o peso dessa informação? Parece óbvio que diferenças maiores entre a idade de indivíduos diminuem um bocado a compatibilidade, mas isso não é necessariamente verdade porque há inúmeros exemplos na vida real que refutam essa intuição.

Eu desconheço em detalhes a forma empregada pelas empresas/sistemas que prestam esse tipo de serviço  (aliás, esse é o seu mais importante dever de casa! Procure entender como a concorrência faz), mas *minha intuição* me diz que a verificação de compatibilidade não é algo assim tão simples como medir a similaridade entre indivíduos por meio de suas características ou preferências.

A compatibilidade depende principalmente de preferências pessoais que não são exatamente as preferências a respeito de parceiros (poderia-se dizer que são meta-preferências; por exemplo, a "cor dos olhos" pode ser mais ou menos importante para diferentes indivíduos). Além disso, a compatibilidade pode variar também com o contexto (local ou temporal): por exemplo, pessoas famosas influenciam bastante as preferências estéticas e comportamentais dos demais indivíduos.

Por isso, mesmo que a abordagem da média ponderada possa ser útil em uma primeira versão do seu sistema, seguramente você precisará utilizar métodos mais rebuscados para conseguir concorrer com o que já existe.

Métricas de compatibilidade úteis seguramente utilizariam uma combinação da compatibilidade individual (medida por exemplo de uma forma sugerida anteriormente) e outras métricas mais subjetivas. Você deve ter percebido que uma métrica "na moda" é a compatibilidade social (isto é, resultante da avaliação da própria "comunidade" a respeito dos indivíduos), mas isso é ao mesmo tempo interessante e polêmico (vide as discussões sobre aplicativos como [Lulu](http://tecnologia.terra.com.br/internet/lulu-muda-no-brasil-e-so-homens-que-optarem-serao-avaliados-no-app,770cef1b0a2f2410VgnVCM3000009af154d0RCRD.html) e [Tinder](http://www.otempo.com.br/interessa/tecnologia-e-games/aplicativo-para-celular-tinder-%C3%A9-a-nova-febre-para-conhecer-algu%C3%A9m-1.741955)). Provavelmente o futuro reserva potencial para a aplicação de abordagens similares à do NetFlix, isto é, um [sistema de recomendação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o) em que o histórico de escolhas e avaliações sejam utilizados para "prever" os gostos futuros.

De todas as formas, se o seu sistema incluir pesos diferentes para as características, uma opção que pode ser fácil de implementar e produzir resultados satisfatórios pode ser permitir que os usuários avaliem os resultados exibidos (em termos de gostei e não gostei). Com base na avaliação, os próprios pesos poderiam ser INDIVIDUALMENTE ajustados de forma dinâmica.

Comment: A ideia foi excelente! e para minha sorte todos os campos são inteiros(representam valores pré-definidos). e a ideia de guardar uma tabela com as comparações de todos os usuários foi o ponto mais interessante pra mim, pois realmente fazer o sistema gerar toda a comparação no momento da consulta seria a maior burrice que eu faria... Apesar de eu não ter entendido a segunda fórmula que você apresentou a ideia e a lógica cumprem exatamente oque eu preciso, sendo assim, mais tarde posso deixar aqui o resultado final desse trabalho :D muito obrigado pela a ajuda e pelo tempo gasto

Comment: A "segunda fórmula" é apenas para exemplificar a média ponderada (se você optar por usar pesos - senão é como se todos os pesos valessem 1 e você apenas somou os valores das similaridades de cada campo e dividiu pelo total de campos). Depois que tiver o seu resultado, poste uma resposta própria. :)

Comment: Bom, agora veio uma duvida pior, se eu criar uma tabela no banco de dados pra isso, como vou fazer pra atualizar ela a cada alteração do perfil do usuário? se eu tiver muitos usuários terei que atualizar milhões de registros por segundo o servidor só tem 8gb de ram e não vai aguentar...

Comment: @RodrigoBorth: Quando você tiver os milhões de usuários, provavelmente seja mais fácil aumentar a capacidade do seu servidor.

Comment: Acho que seria uma tabela para conta aonde logaria o usuário, outra para o perfil, e outra para os "pesos", todas referenciando a mesma conta através de um campo FK conta_id.
Quando você buscar os perfis, use apenas os pesos para filtrar. E se souber como, crie uma tabela para indexação de busca de perfis.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo ai tem que conversar com o meu cliente, que chorou pra pagar 150 por uma vps com backup em hd fisicamente separado pra evitar panes... é uma questão de explicar para alguém, que acha que sabe mais que um programador e na verdade sabe menos que um usuário comum, que o servidor não vai aguentar mais de 10 mil usuários com apenas 8gb de ram... pra você ter noção, pro lançamento do site ele preparou um e-mail marketing com mais de 7 milhoes de emails cadastrados... se 1% entrar simultaneamente o servidor cai.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, se você é programador, deixe este problema com o administrador do servidor.

Comment: @MarceloAymone os pesos são igual pra todas as colunas, porem como o Luiz Vieira disse, não da pra comparar na hora os usuários o melhor é guardar as comparações no banco de dados e atualizar elas, mas ficar atualizando as comparações a cada vez que um usuário se cadastra ou modifica seu perfil não iria gerar muita requisição? (to pensando em abrir uma pergunta sobre isso)

Comment: @MarceloAymone seria fácil assim, mas aqui é uma empresa pequena, todo e qualquer problema referente a um site feito aqui sobra pra quem programou...

Comment: Acho que gera uma boa pergunta, como indexar e atualizar este sistema de comparações... talvez uma Stored procedure? Elas ficam armazenadas no BD e executam mais rápido.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8318/como-indexar-e-atualizar-um-sistema-de-comparacao-de-usuarios coloquei como `sql` a tag

Comment: Provavelmente será mais vantajoso você manter uma versão funcional da tabela de compatibilidades durante o dia (para ser utilizada nas pesquisas) e executar um procedimento (uma *stored procedure*, como sugerido pelo @MarceloAymone) a noite para atualizar as compatibilidades com as alterações do dia anterior. Com o volume de usuários que você está considerando, o fato de não ter as eventuais atualizações aplicadas imediatamente pode passar desapercebido.

Comment: Também acho @LuizVieira...