# Como indexar e atualizar um sistema de comparação de usuários?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas com características e interesses de usuarios em um banco de dados MySQL com innoDB

> Tabela Carateristica

```
id
nome
sobrenome
cidade
estadocivil
altura
peso
fisico
pele
olhos
filhos
querofilhos
bebo
fumo
denominacao
frequencia
importancia
```

> Tabela Interesse

```
id
cidade
estadocivil
altura_min
altura_max
peso_min
peso_max
fisico
pele
olhos
filhos
quer_filhos
bebe
fuma
denominacao
frequencia
importancia
```

no [tópico anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8096/como-fazer-uma-busca-de-perfis-com-caracteristicas-semelhantes-aos-interesses-de), a melhor opção foi criar uma tabela guardando os usuários e sua compatibilidade.

> Tabela de compatibilidade

```
user_id
user_interesse_id
compatibilidade --> Valor de 0 a 100 que representa uma %
```

> O calculo é feito assim:

```
IF($caracteristica==$Interesse)
    $compatibilidade++
```

Depois disso pego o valor final e divido pelo numero de caracteristicas e multiplico por 100
tendo assim uma % de compatibilidade e então armazeno o INT da porcentagem

```
($compatibilidade/Num_car).100;
```

**Agora a questão é: "Como indexar e atualizar essas comparações de forma que não gere mais requisições do que o necessário?"**

@MarceloAymone deu a ideia de uma StoredProcedure que eu ainda não sei direito o que é.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual a tecnologia do banco?

Comment: uso mysql - innoDB

Comment: Uma SP é uma boa idéia quando a execução de uma query é recorrente

Comment: BTW a idéia de uma tabela para relacionar os interesses x características das pessoas não me parece uma boa idéia pois ela vai crescer ao quadrado em relação com o número de pessoas. Para 1.000 pessoas teremos 1.000.000 de compatibilidades

Comment: exatamente por isso que estou buscando alternativas... mas o que exatamente é uma Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que isso seja um tipo de rede social, certo? Não consigo ver como viáveis algoritmos que comparam usuários um a um. Seria muito ineficiente executar isso numa trigger e "demorado" demais num processo em background (quantos minutos o usuário deve esperar para ver o resultado?).

Acredito que a solução ideal seja um tipo de pré-classificação que, aplicada a um determinado usuário, retorne um valor que então possa ser comparado aos demais usuários.

Tentarei ilustrar isso.

Primeiro, vamos tomar por base a **altura**. Imagine que queremos aproximar pessoas com alturas parecidas. Podemos estabelecer faixas de alturas, por exemplo, faixa `1` para pessoas consideradas "baixas", 2 para "medianas" e 3 para "altas".

Para a **cor dos olhos**, poderíamos ter o valor `1` para olhos claros, `2` para castanhos e `3` para escuros.

Para **estado civil**, **fumo**, **bebo** e alguns outros atributos que podem ter apenas dois estados, pode-se adotar os valores `1` e `2`.

Após esta classificação, pode-se pensar em um algoritmo que, a partir de um conjunto de interesses, retorne os perfis mais adequados.

O mais simples poderia ser uma query que compare cada atributo e retorne primeiro aqueles com mais semelhanças.

O exemplo de query abaixo ordena os perfis por semelhança, cujo valor é calculado somando `1` para cada atributo em comum, isto é, quanto mais atributos em comum, maior o valor da coluna:

```sql
select c.*,
( 
  case when faixa_altura = :faixa_altura_interesse then 1 else 0 end +
  case when tipos_olhos = :tipo_olhos_interesse then 1 else 0 end +
  case when bebo = :bebo_interesse then 1 else 0 end +
  (...)
) semelhanca
from caracteristicas c
order by semelhanca desc
```

Outra forma numérica de se fazer isso (que encontrei bem explicada [nesta pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710330/which-algorithm-implementation-for-weighted-similarity-between-users-by-their-se)) é considerar todas essas características como eixos multidimensionais como em um gráfico cartesiano. Então, encontra-se a semelhança entre os interesses e perfis através da "localização" do perfil.

Considere a imagem abaixo ([fonte](http://blog.espol.edu.ec/nemo/2010/12/11/creando-grafico-dispersion-ggplot2-part2/comment-page-1/)):

[image: Gráfico Peso x Altura]

As características de cada perfil são representados por um ponto, certo? Então, para encontrar interesses semelhantes, basta recuperar os pontos mais próximos do interesse.

A diferença é que no seu caso o gráfico teria `N` dimensões, sendo `N` o número de atributos.

Outro fator a se considerar é colocar pesos nessas características. Por exemplo, o fato de beber ou não pode ser mais importante para combinar os perfis do que a altura. Para fazer isso na query mais acima, basta usar, ao invés de `1`, um valor maior de acordo com a importância da característica.

Indo um pouco mais a fundo, se for necessária uma otimização maior e uma query não seja viável, pode-se estabelecer perfis de pessoas. Quando um usuário preencher suas características, o sistema o classifica em um dos tipos cadastrados. Este é apenas mais um tipo de abstração para simplificar a estrutura de dados. Quanto mais perfis houver, mais refinado o resultado será. Este é o método mais "grosso", porém mais eficiente. O ponto fraco é que se alguém não se enquadrar bem num perfil pré-estabelecido, as chances de não encontrar ninguém compatível será maior.

Comment: excelente :D, gostei da ideia dos pontos no plano cartesiano, mas fazer isso com muitas dimensões iria ficar confuso de mais pra mim, já a ideia de padrões de perfis pré estabelecidos poderia ser mais fácil de se implementar além de poder ser aplicado posteriormente uma query para refinar ainda mais o resultado, realmente é algo de se pensar e organizar bem... respondendo sua pergunta, é uma espécie de site de relacionamentos cristão... porém ele se baseia em o dono do site ganhar dinheiro... o usuário grátis simplesmente não pode fazer nada...

Answer (score 2):

Para cada n usuários teremos n-1 comparações, não vi o "sexo" nas tabelas, numa aplicação deste tipo me parece importante.

Eu faria uma tabela em que gravaria os usuários novos ou tivessem tido algum dado cadastrado, um rotina batch(1) (disparada por event) faria a comparação contra os n-1 usuarios e gravaria o para da compatibilidade Usuário x Comparado e Comparado x Usuário pois o que é verdade para usuário x >> usuário y não é verdade para usuário y >> usuário x.
O SQL em si me parece simples : atributo = atributo ou atributo entre intervalo de atributo a questão seria "povoar" as tabelas de relacionamento.

(1) Na realidade duas procedures :

1 Ler linha tabela usuários a processar
  Chama rotina grava Atributos passando usuário como parâmetro
  Deleta usuário da tabela a processar

2 Calcula par de compatibilidade para cada outro usuário da base
  Grava par

Comment: Está um pouco complicado de entender a tua explicação, mas pelo que entendi tu propoe criar 2 tabelas, 1 para gravar o resultado das comparações dos usuarios e outra para grava o resultado final de compatibilidade é isso?

Comment: Creio que qualquer coisa online ficará pesada pois teremos 2X(n-1) comparações entre usuários. Então haveria uma tabela "rascunho" alimentada por trigger com novos usuários e usuários alterados, uma procedure disparada por event numa hora de ociosidade de máquina faria o povoamento dos relaciomentos entre usuários, 2(N-1) pois creio que o relaciomento não é simetrico, a->b <> b->a

Comment: A ideia é boa, vou tentar aplicar ao projeto e ver se é possivel

Answer (score 1):

O ideal pro seu caso é usar uma **Trigger**.

Respondendo ao seu comentário, uma *Stored Procedure* é um conjunto de instruções SQL armazenadas que podem ser executadas através de uma simples chamada. Elas podem receber parâmetros e ter algum comportamento dinâmico.

Mais ou menos na mesma linha, uma *Trigger* também é um conjunto de instruções armazenadas. A diferença dela para as *Stored Procedures* é que a Trigger é chamada automaticamente, porque está amarrada a alguma operação de banco envolvendo uma tabela (inserção de dados em uma tabela, por exemplo).

O exemplo abaixo deixará mais claro o que quero dizer:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER antesDeUpdate_caracteristica 
BEFORE UPDATE ON caracteristica
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE compatibilidade
SET compatibilidade = -- Coloque o valor final aqui
WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id; END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Essa *Trigger* garante que a cada atualização na tabela `caracteristica`, a tabela `compatibilidade` será atualizada.

Não sei como é seu cálculo, mas se você colocar os detalhes do cálculo da compatibilidade na pergunta, posso melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Atualizei com o calculo, e ja tenho varias triggers criadas pra automatizar varias coisas, o problema aqui é onde fazer o calculo, se eu tiver que puxar todos os usuarios no php, realizar o calculo e gravar o resultado isso vai gerar milhões de querys inuteis... esse é o problema, gostaria de uma forma de deixar o SQL calcular por conta em cada update e insert